# Get Facebook feed for a "normal" user

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, social-networking, feed

I would want to read the feed for a given user (a normal user, like me - not a VIP) and I would want to use python. So, I would to use facebook-sdk for Python.

I've written a little code:

```
import facebook
import json
import requests

class FacebookPost:     
    accessToken = ''
    user = 'BillGates'

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(accessToken)
    profile = graph.get_object(user)
    posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

    while True:
        try:
            for post in posts['data']:
                print(post)
        except KeyError:
            break

    data = json.loads(url)

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

It works quite well on Bill Gates profile (a VIP profile, I suppose) but it doesn't work on my profile or my friends' profile.
Is this the right way to resolve the idea? Which is the best way to have normal user facebook's posts?

Comment: you have to authorize the user with the user_posts permission and then use the /mw/feed endpoint to get the feed.

Comment: _“It works quite well on Bill Gates profile (a VIP profile, I suppose)”_ – there is no such thing as a “VIP profile”, that simply is a _page_. This is _not_ a user profile.

Comment: So, I could get just my personal feed and page feed? If an user, not a friend of mine on facebook, doesn't post in public, I cannot get his feed, right?